# How to get the filename of a mongodb GridFS file given its id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

What if I know the mongo id of a file stored in gridFS, and want to download it under the filename that is stored in its fs.files filename field? I don't have a model to call the collection with, so I'm confused how I'm supposed to do a query on that collection.

This is my server.js file, where I connect to the database:

```
require('dotenv').config() 
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => {
        // Listen for requests
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Connected to MongoDB and listening on port`, process.env.PORT)
        })
        
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //throws error if the MONGO_URI string has the wrong user or pw
        console.log(error)
})
```

and in my files controllers file I have this:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 require('dotenv').config()
 const fs = require('fs')

//Create a bucket for storing files
//bucket is initialized to fs and has 2 collections: fs.files and fs.chunks
let bucket
let conn
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    conn = mongoose.connections[0].db
    bucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn)
})

const downloadFileByID = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)){
      return res.status(404).json({error: 'No such file'})
  }
  const mongooseID = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)

  //Get filename
  const cursor = bucket.find({}) //find() returns a FindCursor iterable
  let filename
  for await (const file of cursor) {
    if (file._id == id){
      filename = file.filename
    }
  }

  try{
    bucket.openDownloadStream(mongooseID).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./'+ filename.filename))
    res.send(filename)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({error: "File not found, file ID does not exist"})
  }
}
```

The loop I do to find the filename is not optimal and very slow, but I haven't found another way to access the filename field of fs.files.
Doing `bucket.find({_id: id})` doesn't seem to actually find the file, it returns nothing (I don't think find() takes any arguments). However, the documentations state that there should be a way to get the filename field from the fs.files collection, but doesn't explain how to do it. I'm pretty stuck on this...

Otherwise, I also tried directly querying from the fs.files collection, but since I have no model for that collection, I don't have a model name to do the query on. Most sources use a syntax similar to `db.fs.files.findOne({_id: id}), but I get an error saying that db is not defined. This issue seems easy to solve, but I've been stuck for days.
Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem! The answer was pretty simple, as expected:

```
const files = conn.collection('fs.files')
const filename = await files.findOne({_id: mongooseID}, {projection:{filename : 1, _id : 0}})
```